# Create database view from SQL stored as string in Netezza

Tags: sql, view, dynamic-sql, netezza

I got a task to create a view based on 10 SQL queries, which are stored in one of the tables. In this table, there are two columns. First of them is Site, and the second is mentioned before SQL query.

Now, there whole deal is, that I would like to create a view, with two columns - first would be the name of the Site and the second one would be whatever ID mentioned query returns.

Can anyone please tell me how to execute this string as a query?

I have done something like this couple years ago on SQL Server (using procedure), non the less on Neteeza I can't figure how this should works; as a further complication, we are forbidden to use procedures an PROD.

Comment: You'd do this in a procedure, if you can't use procedures you'll probably have to script this with something that can run queries against your netezza box.

Comment: Well, exactly. I would like do this is, by using a procedure. Non the less i am forced to come up with some other way to solve this issue.

Comment: Python might be a good choice. It seems odd that someone would prohibit procedures but allow outside scripts to run.